# what is the mistake in this code?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

This is my form controller to insert details with image in database table

```
public function store(Applicant $appl, ApplicantForm $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('ppimg_filename'))
    {
        $destinationPath="offerimages";
        $file = $request->file('ppimg_filename');
        $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('ppimg_filename')->move($destinationPath,$filename);
    }

    $a=$appl->create($request->all());

    $a['ppimg_filename'] = $filename;
    return 'done';
}
```

What possibly could cause `error:undefined filename`?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the script flow doesn't execute the code inside if statement. 
Check `ppimg_filename` in html form.

Answer (score 0):

You define `filename` inside an `if` block. If the conditional expression does not evaluate to true then that block will not be entered and the variable will not be created. In that scenario the variable will not exist when you refer to it in the line `$a['ppimg_filename'] = $filename;`. That is probably the reason for your error. You should either handle that case with an `else` block that does not use any variables defined in your `if` block, or create those variables before the `if` block so that you can refer to them afterwards even if the block is not entered.